React hook form trigger not working properly
I'm trying to create a multi step form using react hook form + zod. On the main page I have this
const steps = [
    { name: "Expertise Areas", fields: ["expertise_areas"] },
    { name: "Contact Info", fields: ["full_name", "email", "phone", "company"] },
    { name: "Project Details", fields: ["message"] }
  ]

const {
    register, handleSubmit, trigger, formState: { errors }} = useForm<fastTrackFormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FastTrackSchema),
    mode: "all"
  });

const nextStep = async () => {
    const fields = steps[currentStep - 1].fields;
    const isValid = await trigger(fields as FieldName[], { shouldFocus: true });

    if (!isValid) return;

    if (currentStep < 3) {
      setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
    } else {
      await handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
    }
  }

return (
...

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="flex flex-col gap-4">
            {currentStep === 1 && (
              <Reveal>
                <div className="flex flex-col border-2 rounded-xl p-4 border-base-200 gap-1 w-full">
                  {expertise_areas.map((area, index) => (
                    <FormCheckbox
                      key={index}
                      label={t(`fast_track.${area}`)}
                      inputProps={{ ...register(`expertise_areas.${area}`) }}
                    />
                  ))}
                  <FormCheckbox
                    label={t("fast_track.other")}
                    inputProps={{
                      ...register("expertise_areas.other",
                        { onChange: (e) => handleShowOther(e.target.checked) }
                      )
                    }}
                  />
                  {showOtherInput && (
                    <FormInput
                      id="expertise_areas"
                      label={t("fast_track.other")}
                      type="text"
                      placeholder={t("fast_track.other_description")}
                      inputProps={{ ...register("expertise_areas.other_service") }}
                    />
                  )}
                  <span className="text-error text-sm text-right mt-3 font-light">
                    {errors.expertise_areas && t("fast_track.expertise_areas_required")}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </Reveal>
            )}

            {currentStep === 2 && (
              <Reveal>
                <div className="flex flex-col border-2 rounded-xl p-4 border-base-200 gap-4 w-full">
                  <FormInput
                    id="full_name"
                    label={t("fast_track.full_name")}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("fast_track.full_name")}
                    inputProps={{ ...register("full_name") }}
                    error={errors.full_name ? true : false}
                    errorMessage={errors.full_name?.message}
                  />
                  <FormInput
                    id="email"
                    label={t("fast_track.email")}
                    type="email"
                    placeholder={t("fast_track.email")}
                    inputProps={{ ...register("email") }}
                    error={errors.email ? true : false}
                    errorMessage={errors.email?.message}
                  />
                  <FormInput
                    id="phone"
                    label={t("fast_track.phone")}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("fast_track.phone")}
                    inputProps={{ ...register("phone") }}
                    error={errors.phone ? true : false}
                    errorMessage={errors.phone?.message}
                  />
                  <FormInput
                    id="company"
                    label={t("fast_track.company")}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("fast_track.company")}
                    inputProps={{ ...register("company") }}
                    error={errors.company ? true : false}
                    errorMessage={errors.company?.message}
                  />
                </div>
              </Reveal>
            )}
            <div className="flex justify-between">
              {currentStep > 1 && (
                <div className="mr-auto">
                  <DefaultButton onClick={previousStep}>
                    {t("fast_track.previous")}
                  </DefaultButton>
                </div>
              )}
              <div className="ml-auto">
                <Reveal>
                  <DefaultButton onClick={nextStep}>
                    {currentStep < 3 ? t("fast_track.next") : t("fast_track.submit")}
                  </DefaultButton>
                </Reveal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
...

And the zod schema is like this:
import { z } from "zod";
import { useTranslation } from "../hooks/useTranslation";
import i18n from "../i18n";

const expertise_areas = z.object({
    ich_m7: z.boolean(),
    expert_reviews: z.boolean(),
    limits: z.boolean(),
    degradation: z.boolean(),
    nitrosamins: z.boolean(),
    qualification: z.boolean(),
    purge: z.boolean(),
    other: z.boolean(),
    other_service: z.string().optional(),
})


const createFastTrackSchema = (t: (key: string) => string | undefined) => {
    return z.object({
        expertise_areas: expertise_areas,
        full_name: z.string().min(1, { message: t("fast_track.full_name_required") }),
        email: z.string()
            .min(1, { message: t("fast_track.email_required") })
            .email({ message: t("fast_track.email_invalid") }),
        phone: z.string().min(1, { message: t("fast_track.phone_required") }),
        company: z.string().min(1, { message: t("fast_track.company_required") }),
        country: z.string().min(1, { message: t("fast_track.country_required") }),
        message: z.string().min(1, { message: t("fast_track.message_required") }),
    });
};

export const useFastTrackSchema = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation(i18n);
    return createFastTrackSchema(t);
};

This is my DefaultButton code:
const DefaultButton: FC<DefaultButtonProps> = ({
  animate,
  children,
  href,
  rounded = false,
  outlined = false,
  shorten = false,
  bg = "btn-primary",
  fullWidth = false,
  newTab = false,
  loading = false,
  onClick,
}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (href) {
      if (newTab) {
        window.open(href, "_blank");
        return;
      }
      router.push(href);
    }
  };
  return outlined ? (
    <button
      onClick={onClick || handleClick}
      disabled={loading}
      className={`btn text-sm ${rounded
        ? "text-base-content border-base-300"
        : "text-primary py-0 border-2 border-primary"
        } bg-base-100 ${shorten ? "px-2" : "px-8"} ${animate} ${fullWidth ? "w-full" : ""
        }
       hover:bg-base-200 hover:border-primary`}
    >
      {loading ? (
        <span className="loading loading-dots"></span>)
        : children}
    </button>
  ) : (
    <button
      onClick={onClick || handleClick}
      disabled={loading}
      className={`btn text-sm ${rounded
        ? "text-base-content border-base-200 hover:bg-base-300 hover:border-base-300 bg-base-200"
        : "text-white py-0"
        } ${bg} ${shorten ? "px-2" : "px-8"} ${animate} ${fullWidth ? "w-full" : ""
        }`}
    >

      {loading ? (
        <span className="loading loading-dots"></span>)
        : children}
    </button>
  );
};

When I click the NEXT button, it should validate only the fields of the current step. However, for some reason I don't know, it's validating all fields. So it moves to the next step but on the next step all fields are already with errors and in red.
Does anyone know what could be wrong here?

Is your next button submitting the form and triggering form validation? Can you [edit] to include the DefaultButton component code, any other code and details, and exact reproduction steps?

@drew-reese Sure thing. Just edited the question and included de DefaultButton code. Now that you mentioned that, it might be trying to submit, but I dont know why it would, since I'm providing an onClick method to it

As drew-reese suggested, the button was actually triggering the method nextStep and also submitting the form, since the button didn't have a type="button" property.
It is inside a form, so it's treated like a submit button. Adding type="button" to the DefaultButton component solved the problem.
